# js - pass extra param to callback function

Tags: javascript, qt, pyqt5, arrow-functions

I'm trying to pass an extra param to a 3rd callback function (its not my own callback).

```
const selectedItems = dt.rows({ selected: true });
const selectedIndexes = selectedItems.indexes();
const selectedData = selectedItems.data();

let data_object = [];

$.each(selectedData, (i, o) => {
  data_object.push(o['PackageName']);
});

window.bridge.deleteApps(data_object, (success_list, selectedIndexes) => {
  console.log("test"); // selectedIndexes -> undefined

});
```

Background: It's a function that comes with Qt that triggers a python method (pyqt), the first param is passed to python the second param is a callback function with the return from the python method (`success_list`) but i need `selectedIndexes` too.

When I do

```
window.bridge.deleteApps(data_object, (success_list, abc=selectedIndexes) => {
  console.log("test"); // abc + selectedIndexes is available

});
```

I'm sorry that I've no working snippet for you to test but I did some researchs about callbacks and actually don't understand it, so I'm not able to reproduce this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think part of your confusion is how callbacks are handled. Basically it's up to the `window.bridge.deleteApps` function to pass parameters to the callback you provide. So unless you're the author of that function, there's not a good way to have it pass you additional parameters. However, in the above example you should have access to `selectedIndexes` because you've declared it with `const` and it will be accessible from your callback.

So you should be able to have this code:

```
window.bridge.deleteApps(data_object, (success_list) => {
  console.log(selectedIndexes); // Should be available because you've declared it in a higher scope
  console.log(success_list); // Gets passed by the .deleteApss function
});
```

Comment: omg your are right...I'm confused AF, thats what i tried first and iam pretty sure it said `selectedIndexes is undefined` -.-

Comment: If you're using `const selectedIndexes = selectedItems.indexes();` as your call to get a value for `selectedIndexes`, are you sure that you're actually getting a value back from that? Can you log what `selectedIndexes` is before you actually make any other calls?

Comment: Yes it's working fine now. I'm pretty sure that i got an `undefined` error when  it was accessing the callback function yesterday so thats why i was even asking for help but now i can easily access the variable inside the callback...so finally there never existed a problem :S Thanks for ya help!

Comment: You're very welcome! I +1 on the answer is much appreciated ;)